# How do I get access to my customers account from my facebook app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created a facebook app (which is currently in dev stage, hence not approved by FB yet).
I need to get the daily ads insights reports for all my customers, so I need them to grant access for my app (ads_read).

I do not understand and cannot find it in the documentation, how do I get my customers to grant me (my app) access to their ads accounts.
Do I need to setup a Business Manager? 
thanks

I tried using app token but it only accesses my accounts

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

- Add them to your App as Test Users, so they can use the permissions without review
- Go through review with the neccessary permissions

An App Token does not have any relation to a User, so you cannot even get access to your own Ads with that one. You are probably talking about a User or Page Token.

More information about Tokens: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/